# I need to run udeploy script to weblogic server. Basically this is patching script in power shell. How can I do this. Do I need to install any agent?

Tags: powershell, weblogic11g, udeploy

Need to run script on weblogic servers through udeploy. Do I need to install any agent, I got know agent is Weblogic WLDeploy but not sure.
This is power shell script i.e patching script.
Please help how to do this.

I checked the design screen in UCD and found out their are different components, out of which 'Run power shell script' and Run WL Deploy I found. Then checked the properties.
For testing tried to run the  .ps script but got failed.